# FFmpeg Python Encode Script Improvements

Tags: python, ffmpeg

Im using a ffpmeg script to encode videos into multiple mp4 qualities, This is only a basic script, need suggestion for how to improve speed and performance. This script encode mp4 videos into 720p and 360p, i think some flags can make better performance lie quickstart but not sure that why asking help

```
# encoding: utf-8
# coder:    silip Tv
# version:  1.0

import os
import subprocess
import sys
import time
import re
import datetime

os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0])))

print()
print('*' * 34)
print('** Real-time Video Encoder v1.0 **')
print('*' * 34)
print()

paths = {
    "src_dir" : "/www/wwwroot/videos/mp4/source",
    "out_dir" : "/www/wwwroot/videos/mp4/pinoy"
}

src_dir = paths['src_dir']
out_dir = paths['out_dir']

if not os.path.exists(src_dir):
    print('Source directory specified in "paths" dictionary is not valid.')
    exit()

elif not os.path.exists(out_dir):
    print('Output directory specified in "paths" dictionary is not valid.')
    exit()

# --------------------------------------------------------------------

last_act = 'encoding'

while True:
    if last_act == 'encoding':
        print('Watching source folder for incoming video files...')

    last_act = 'waiting'

    cur_date = datetime.datetime.now().date()
    cur_yr = str(cur_date.year)
    cur_mon = str(cur_date.month).zfill(2)
    cur_day = str(cur_date.day).zfill(2)

    src_files = os.listdir(src_dir)
    src_files = [eve for eve in src_files if eve.lower().endswith('.mp4')]
    src_files.sort(key=lambda x: os.path.getctime(src_dir + '/' + x))

    if src_files:
        src_file = src_files[0]
        print('Processing "{}"'.format(src_file))

        dest_dir = '{}/{}/{}/{}/{}'.format(out_dir, cur_yr, cur_mon, cur_day, src_file.rsplit('.', 1)[0])
        os.makedirs(dest_dir, exist_ok=True)

        ffmpeg_com = 'ffmpeg -y -loglevel error -i "{}/{}" -i watermark_360p.png -filter_complex "scale=640:360,overlay=0:0" -codec:a copy "{}/360.mp4"'.format(src_dir, src_file, dest_dir)
        subprocess.call(ffmpeg_com, shell=True)
        ffmpeg_wm_com = 'ffmpeg -y -loglevel error -ss 0:0:10 -i "{}/360.mp4" -vframes 1 -q:v 2 "{}/poster.jpg"'.format(dest_dir, dest_dir)
        subprocess.call(ffmpeg_wm_com, shell=True)

        ffprobe_com = 'ffprobe -loglevel error -i "{}/{}" -show_streams'.format(src_dir, src_file)
        ffprobe_com_out = subprocess.check_output(ffprobe_com, shell=True).decode('utf-8')
        height = re.search('(?<=\nheight=)\d+', ffprobe_com_out)
        height = int(ffprobe_com_out[height.start():height.end()])

        if height >= 720:
            ffmpeg_com = 'ffmpeg -y -loglevel error -i "{}/{}" -i watermark_720p.png -filter_complex "scale=1280:720,overlay=0:0" -codec:a copy "{}/720.mp4"'.format(
                src_dir, src_file, dest_dir)
            subprocess.call(ffmpeg_com, shell=True)
            ffmpeg_wm_com = 'ffmpeg -y -loglevel error -ss 0:0:10 -i "{}/720.mp4" -vframes 1 -q:v 2 "{}/poster.jpg"'.format(
                dest_dir, dest_dir)
            subprocess.call(ffmpeg_wm_com, shell=True)

        os.remove(src_dir + '/' + src_file)

        last_act = 'encoding'

    time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: How much CPU utilization currently? Do you have any bitrate target? (that is, large files acceptable?) How about quality? You can start with `-preset ultrafast`. Read up on [the guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264) if you haven't already.

Comment: currently using very high cpu load, any idea to decrease it?

Comment: FFmpeg should load CPU heavily to do its job. How long it takes depends on your compression/quality settings. Obviously lower compression and lower quality mean less work for FFmpeg, but you need to decide what is acceptable for your task. The wiki link in my first comment is a good place for you to start. Also, if you have a potent GPU, you can look into [hardware acceleration](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HWAccelIntro)

Comment: thanks for your quick replay, could you help to customize my script? im not a dev just trying to find some help, as i have to use this script for long time

Comment: updated code, any suggetsion?

ffmpeg_com = 'ffmpeg -y -loglevel error -i "{}/{}" -i silip-720.png -filter_complex "scale=1280:720,overlay=0:0" -codec:a copy -c:v libx264 -preset medium -crf 23 -color_primaries bt709 -color_trc bt709 -colorspace bt709 -movflags +faststart -color_range tv -pix_fmt yuv420p "{}/720.mp4"'.format(src_dir, src_file, dest_dir)
   subprocess.call(ffmpeg_com, shell=True)